# div onclick not firing in IE 8 and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, google-chrome, internet-explorer-8

I have the following javascript function in my application which is expected to perform grid filtering based on the div click, but the major problem i am facing is that the div click is working fine in mozilla firefox , but not in IE 8 and chrome, can anyone help to figure the issue related to this function

```
$(function(){
    $('#FileDiv').live('click', function (e) {
       alert(1);

    });
});
```

Comment: What is the `$find` function?

Comment: What is $find? Maybe a typo? Jynx btw

Comment: I am using aspx page, not the plane html, $find  is used to fetch the id of severside control from javascript

Comment: This is my code for div ,<div id="FileDiv"  class="sh1">
                          <asp:Literal ID="FileLiteral" runat="server" ></asp:Literal>
                           </div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need the HTML to verify, but here's where I've run into trouble with this:

1. Make sure a div with id="FileDiv" is actually there. I see you're using ASP.NET and I have spent time debugging client-side code affecting content that was not delivered becuase of server-side logic. Real forehead-smacking stuff.
2. Try other events. Instead of live, try straight-click to see if that matters.
3. Make sure your function is being called on document-load. I suspect it isn't.